# If the principal office is changed with the state of incorporation, do articles of incorporation have to have the new location of the company?

Tags: united-states, corporate-law

If the principal office is changed with the state of incorporation, do articles of incorporation have to have the new location of the company?

Answer (score 0):

> If the principal office is changed with the state of incorporation, do
> articles of incorporation have to have the new location of the
> company?

The predominant rule in U.S. jurisdictions is "no", you don't need to change the articles of incorporation to change a principal office if you notify the appropriate official in the state of incorporation. But the articles do have to be redone if the entity changes its state of incorporation.

But there are fifty U.S. states and there are several more U.S. jurisdictions in which you can incorporate. I wouldn't promise that there aren't a few that are quirky and require an amendment to the articles of incorporation even though that would be a decidely minority rule.